# How to bring last next() element back to the first in the list?

Tags: jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/2z9unx02/12/

I have a lightbox gallery that is scrolling through images. When I reach the very end or the beginning it freezes on the last picture. I would like the photos to cycle through going either direction. previous or next. How can I trigger the last li to go back to the first and vice versa? Thanks in advance.

```
$buttonLeft.click(function() {
    var temp = $("li.active").parents("div.pic_wrapper").prev();
    var imageLocation = temp.find("a").attr("href");
    var captionText = temp.find("img").attr("alt");    
    updateImage(imageLocation, captionText);
    $("li.active").removeClass("active");
    temp.find("li").addClass("active");
});

$buttonRight.click(function() {
    var temp = $("li.active").parents("div.pic_wrapper").next();
    var imageLocation = temp.find("a").attr("href");
    var captionText = temp.find("img").attr("alt");    
    updateImage(imageLocation, captionText);
    $("li.active").removeClass("active");
    temp.find("li").addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this:

```
var temp = $("li.active").parents("div.pic_wrapper").next();
```

..add the following:

```
temp = temp.length ? temp : $('li.active').parents('div.pic_wrapper').siblings().first();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works perfectly. I'm trying to wrap my head around this Ternary Operator. I've tried to write it as an if statement but can't seem to wrap my head around it. I'm mostly confused about the condition and first expression and how this line of code actually works.

Comment: This should do:  `if( !temp.length ) { $('li.active').parents('div.pic_wrapper').siblings().first(); }`

Comment: Another way to achieve the same result is: `temp.length ||  $('li.active').parents('div.pic_wrapper').siblings().first();`